# Titanium Video Player in Landscape mode

Tags: video, titanium-mobile

I want to add a video in Titanium, but unfortunately it inserts it in Portrait mode. How do I turn it to landscape without the controls also turning?

The code below shows it tall and skinny.

```
var videoPlayer = Ti.Media.createVideoPlayer({
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    media:movieFile,
    width: 280,
    height: 187,
    //top:2,
    mediaControlStyle : Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_DEFAULT,
    scalingMode : Titanium.Media.VIDEO_SCALING_ASPECT_FIT
});
```

Thanks

Comment: The only way to change from portrait to landscape is if the user rotates their device 90 degrees. Are you developing for android or iphone? You can lock the screen orientation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply it seems that. That's how it works but it is strange. It depends if the phone detects the orientation correctly while you film.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var videoPlayer = Ti.Media.createVideoPlayer({
backgroundColor: 'red',
media:movieFile,
width: 187,
height: 280,
//top:2,
mediaControlStyle : Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_DEFAULT,
scalingMode : Titanium.Media.VIDEO_SCALING_ASPECT_FIT
});
```